On the error term in a result of Fouvry and Iwaniec
I am currently following the paper On a theorem of Bombieri-Vinogradov type by E. Fouvry and H. Iwaniec. They showed that when $f_z(n)$ is the characteristic function for integers free of prime divisors $<z$, $A>0$, $|a|\le x$, $\theta={11\over 21}$, and $z\le x^{1/883}$, there is
$$
\sum_{\substack{q\le x^\theta\\(q,a)=1}}\left|\sum_{\substack{n\le x\\n\equiv a(q)}}f_z(n)-{1\over\varphi(q)}\sum_{\substack{n\le x\\(n,q)=1}}f_z(n)\right|\ll_Ax(\log x)^{-A}.
$$
A crucial step towards the proof of this result is the estimation of a term they called $D_p(M,Q)$ (p. 144). Firstly, they expand it in the following manner
$$
D_p(M,Q)=W_p(M,Q)-2V_p(M,Q)+U_p(M,Q).
$$
Then by estimating Kloosterman sums, they showed that (equation (15) in p. 146):
$$
V_p(M,Q)-U_p(M,Q)\ll N^2Q^{-1}x^\varepsilon+MN^2Q^{-1}x^{-2\varepsilon}+(a,p)^{1/2}p^{1/2}N^{5/2}Q^{-1}x^{5\varepsilon}\tag{$*$}
$$
As for $W_p(M,Q)$, they extracted a main term $T_p(M,Q)$ and deduced that (bottom of p. 146 and equation (23) of p. 150):
$$
\begin{aligned}
W_p(M,Q)-T_p(M,Q)
&\ll MN^2Q^{-1}p^{-1}+N^2Q^{-1}\log Q+MN\log x \\
&+MN^2Q^{-1}x^{-2\varepsilon}+(a,p)^{1/10}p^{13/10}N^{29/10}Q^{-1}x^{7\varepsilon}.
\end{aligned}\tag{$**$}
$$
Accordingly, the main term of $D_p(M,Q)$ is
$$
X_p(M,Q)=T_p(M,Q)-2U_p(M,Q)+U_p(M,Q),
$$
and the error $R_p(M,Q)=D_p(M,Q)-X_p(M,Q)$ is naturally given by the combination of (*) and (**). However, on the bottom of page 150, they wrote
$$
\begin{aligned}
R_p(M,Q)
&\ll MN^2Q^{-1}x^{-2\varepsilon}+N^2Q^{-1}x^\varepsilon+MN^2Q^{-1}p^{-1} \\
&+MNx^\varepsilon+\color{red}{Qx^\varepsilon}+(a,p)^{1/10}p^{13/10}N^{29/10}Q^{-1}x^{7\varepsilon}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Every other term comes from (*) and (**), but I am confused about where $Qx^\varepsilon$ comes from as I can only find $Q^{-1}$ in all other relevant estimates before $R_p(M,Q)$. This term is crucial as it sets the limit $\theta={11\over21}$ in their result.
As a result, I wonder if anybody familiar with their work can help me identify the origin of this mysterious term.

Notice that the bound on the right hand side would have no positive dependence on $Q$ if this term was not there. Indeed, one would have the rather incredulous conclusion that the right hand side remains bounded as $Q$ tends to infinity independent of $M,N,x$. The bound comes from the trivial bound on the outer sum.

For your information, it was also assumed at the very beginning that $QD\ll x^{1-2\varepsilon}$, where $D$ is a parameter in a combinatorial identity.

"This term is crucial as it sets the limit $\theta=\frac{11}{21}$ in their result.'' - care to elaborate? In bottom of page 151 it seems that the term $Qx^{\varepsilon}$ leads to the error term $z^{1/2} D^{1/2} Q x^{\varepsilon}$ which the authors want to bound by $\ll x (\log x)^{-A-2}$. I do not see why this term influences the final range of $z$, but I might be missing something of course.

After examining the derivations closely, I realize that their conclusions are unaffected by $z^{1/2}D^{1/2}Qx^\varepsilon$, so I guess the authors just forgot to remove extra terms after optimizing their methods.

After examining all the derivations, I concluded that the result is unaffected by the presence of the red term. Perhaps the authors optimized their methods but forgot to remove extra terms in $D_p(M,Q)$.
Specifically, If one were to follow the entire argument, then he/she will reach the following in the end
$$
\ll x(\log x)^{-A-2}+zD^{-1/2}x^{1+\varepsilon}+D^{1/2}Q^{1/2}x^{1/2+\varepsilon}+\color{red}{z^{1/2}D^{1/2}Qx^{\varepsilon}}+z^{21/10}D^{-19/20}x^{29/20+5\varepsilon}
$$
Write $D=x^\alpha$, $z=x^\beta$, and $Q=x^\theta$. To make sure the whole term is $\ll x(\log x)^{-A-2}$, we essentially need
$$
\beta-\frac12\alpha<0,\quad\alpha+\theta<1,\quad\color{red}{\frac12\alpha+\frac12\beta+\theta<1},\quad {21\over10}\beta-{19\over20}\alpha<-{9\over20}.
$$
By the first two inequalities, we have
$$
\frac12\alpha+\frac12\beta+\theta<\frac12\alpha+\frac12\beta+1-\alpha<1-\frac\alpha4,
$$
so the red inequality is automatically satisfied. As a result, this term indeed has no impact on the choice of $\theta$.
For the sake of completeness, I also include the arguments leading to the admissibility of $\beta={1\over 883}$ and $\theta={11\over21}$:
Since the goal is to make some $\theta>1/2$ admissible, we need $\alpha<\frac12$. As a result, we take a simple fraction $\alpha={10\over21}$ that works, so the third inequality implies
$$
{21\over10}\beta-{19\over20}\cdot{10\over21}<{-9\over20}\implies\beta<{1\over882},
$$
so $\beta={1\over883}$ and $\theta<{11\over21}$ are acceptable. If we make $\alpha$ slightly less than $10\over21$, then $\beta={1\over883}$ still works and we can set $\theta$ to exactly ${11\over21}>\frac12$.
